# How to fix Error: Formula `dbus` has not implemented #plist, #service or installed a locatable service file

Tags: service, homebrew, plist, dbus

I want to install dbus service in homebrew to use vimtex with zathura on macos 13.3.1
However I get this error:

```
brew services start dbus
```

```
Error: Formula `dbus` has not implemented #plist, #service or installed a locatable service file
```

The following output when I try to check on dbus:

```
 brew services info dbus
```

```
dbus (homebrew.mxcl.dbus)
Running: ✘
Loaded: ✘
Schedulable: ✘
```

I tried starting the service with launchctl:

```
launchctl list | grep dbus
```

```
-   0   org.freedesktop.dbus-session`
```

The plist file seems to exist in /usr/local/opt/dbus/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist

Thanks for any pointer towards what I could try

I would like the output of brew service start dbus to be successfull and start the service at login.